# Connect Azure Active Directory to on premise customer AD

Tags: single-sign-on, entra-id

We have a web application running in Windows Azure where a variety of customers can log in. Lately more and more of them have been asking for some sort of single sign on solution, or at least a synchronization of their local/domain users with the ones present in our application. I've looked at several options but haven't really found one that looks feasible to me. Below I've listed what I've been looking at, but basically I would like some advice on how to approach this problem.

There are third party services that might be able to do this, but usually those require some or a lot of work both for us and our customers to implement. This could also mean we would have to implement multiple or a lot of these solutions depending on customer preference.

Most if not all of our customers will have an on premise Active Directory and it would be perfect if we could somehow use that with our application as well. Connecting our web app to an on premise AD isn't really an option because sys admins (understandably) won't give us access to it.

We can setup an AD in Azure as well. So I thought that maybe we could sync from the on premise AD to our AD in Azure and then take it from there. However when testing Microsofts Azure Active Directory Connect tool, it asked me for an administrator login for our Azure environment. Obviously we don't want to give our customers access to our Azure portal, so it looks like this isn't going to work as well.

Another problem in all this is that I'm a programmer and all the AD stuff is a little out of my comfort zone and I might be looking in the wrong places.

Does anyone have any experience with any of this, and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: You generally wouldn't connect directly with the users AD, rather you would connect to ADFS via a proxy. Other then that microsoft have a product in beta called Azure Active Directory B2C. Which would allow users to use social accounts to connect

Comment: Thanks for the reply. While searching the internet, seems that's about all I'm doing these days, I came across ADFS. Trying to set that up in a test environment is a whole new problem, but it looks like that's the way to go.

Comment: DirSync/ADConnect + ADFS will provide you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

ADConnect is the way to sync the on-premise directory with your cloud. It asks for a username password to set-up the initial sync and to make changes to the sync if you are logging in again with the tool. You'd also need a DA account for a local administrator while you set it up. If you have neither one or none of the two accounts, you can't complete the set up.

Going by what you are suggesting, Azure B2C is what you are looking to set up. Else, set up ADFS federation between your domains and the customer domains so that you don't have to scratch around asking for any username/passwords. I am assuming your applications is a claims aware and you have your own Windows AD to let ADFS to be configured.

If you are trying to set up a ADFS test environment, I followed the 4 part blog to build my first lab - hopefully it should work OK for you too.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/12/09/how-to-build-your-adfs-lab-on-server-2012-part-1.aspx
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/12/23/how-to-build-your-adfs-lab-on-server-2012-part2-web-sso.aspx

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2014/03/17/how-to-build-your-adfs-lab-on-server-2012-part-3-adfs-proxy.aspx
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2014/03/31/how-to-build-your-adfs-lab-part4-upgrading-to-server-2012-r2.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you configure the application to support SAML authentication - than a customer could configure their ADFS (or other) to work with their AD.  This is typically how that is handled for SSO to third party applications.

The way that works is you still manage identities and access to the application but customers are able to take that and tie it to their own "claim" that can contain AD usernames.  This is what ADFS as well as other federating identity platforms do (the federation part). You do need to provide a way to create the trust however, between identity providers (yours and theirs).

On your side you can create a custom identity provider, use a third party service, or deploy a federation server like ADFS.  But there are others as well (both commercial and open source) like PingFederate and Shibboleth. There are literally hundreds of options there.  If you want an SDK - Ping Identity (PingFederate developers) offer one for multiple languages (Java, C#, etc).  I'm sure there are open source SDK's out there as well to help with it.

Identity is complex topic - the more you can offload that to a dedicated company or team the better off you will be (Azure B2C is in preview as stated in other answers but look at 3rd parties if you are looking to get going faster)

Comment: Didn't know about Azure B2C, although I think we're more in B2B territory I'll have to check that out as well.